D3.js How to fit and center text along an textPath inside an arc
Is it possible to center my text vertically in the ARC`s?
If you look at my example, you can see that the text in the first ring has a lot of space at the top and is not centered correctly.
I tried text-align and content-align for every "textPath", but neither worked.
I would be very grateful for any advice!
Kind Regards Jegor
Using library D3.v7.js


// Data
const data1 = {
  "name": "AB-C-1 <br> Dept.15 <br> Marketing <br> Müller",
  "id": 1,
  "children": [{
    "name": "Topic A <br> Description <br> Dept.15 <br> Marketing <br> Müller ",
    "id": 2,
    "size": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Topic B <br> test",
    "id": 3,
    "size": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Topic C",
    "id": 4,
    "size": 4
  }]
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
// Declare variables
let i_region_static_id = "sunburst",
    parentDiv = document.getElementById(i_region_static_id),
    width = parentDiv.clientWidth,
    height = 450,
    root,
    rootDepth,
    x,
    y,
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
maxRadius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 5;


const partition = d3.partition();
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SVG-Element
let svg = d3.select('#' + i_region_static_id).append('svg')
  .style('width', width)
  .style('height', height)
  .attr('viewBox', `${-width / 2} ${-height / 2} ${width} ${height}`)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// X-Scale
x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, 2 * Math.PI])
  .clamp(true);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Y-Scale
y = d3.scaleSqrt()
  .range([maxRadius * .1, maxRadius]);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create Arc generator
const arc = d3.arc()
  .startAngle(d => x(d.x0))
  .endAngle(d => x(d.x1))
  .innerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y0)))
  .outerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y1)))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const middleArcLine = d => {
  const halfPi = Math.PI / 2;
  const angles = [x(d.x0) - halfPi, x(d.x1) - halfPi];
  const r = Math.max(0, (y(d.y0) + y(d.y1)) / 2);

  const middleAngle = (angles[1] + angles[0]) / 2;
  const invertDirection = middleAngle > 0 && middleAngle < Math.PI; // On lower quadrants write text ccw
  if (invertDirection) {
    angles.reverse();
  }

  const path = d3.path();
  path.arc(0, 0, r, angles[0], angles[1], invertDirection);
  return path.toString();
}


function wrap(text, index) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        letters = text.text().split(' <br> ').reverse(),
        letter,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        //dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        textPath = text.append("textPath") // Add a textPath element
    .attr('startOffset', '50%')
    .attr('fill', d => 'black')
    .attr('xlink:href', function(d) {
      return "#hiddenArc" + index;
    }),
        tspan = textPath.append('tspan') // Inslide textPath, add a tspan element, for offset feature later.

    while (letter = letters.pop()) {
      line.push(letter);
      tspan.text(line.join(""));
      if (line.length > 1) {
        // if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(""));
        line = [letter];

        textPath = text.append("textPath")
          .attr('startOffset', '50%')
          .attr('fill', d => 'black')
          .attr('xlink:href', function(d, i) {
          return "#hiddenArc" + index;
        }),

          // Add a tspan element to offset the wrapped letters from the previous line
          tspan = textPath.append("tspan")
          .attr('dy', ++lineNumber + 'em')
        //.attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .text(letter);
      }
    }
  });
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Initialize and Update sun 
function updateSun(pData) {

  const valueAccessor = (d) => d.size;

  root = d3.hierarchy(pData); //set data

  valueAccessor == null ? root.count() : root.sum((d) => Math.max(0, valueAccessor(d)));

  // Sortiert Nodes
  root.sort((d) => d3.descending(d.value))

  const slice = svg.selectAll('g.slice')
  .data(
    partition(root).descendants(),
    function(d) {
      return d.data.id;
    }
  );

  // Enter Section
  const newSlice = slice.enter()
  .append('g').attr('class', 'slice')
  .attr('display', d => d.depth < 2 ? null : 'none') // Hide levels lower depth

  .each(function(d, i) {
    // Append main-arc
    d3.select(this).append('path')
      .attr('class', 'main-arc')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .style('fill', d => (d.data.color == undefined) ? color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name) : d.data.color)

    // Append hidden-arc
    d3.select(this).append('path')
      .attr('class', 'hidden-arc')
      .attr('d', middleArcLine)
      .attr('id', 'hiddenArc' + i)

    // Append text
    d3.select(this).append('text')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
      .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    })
      .style('fill', 'none')
      .call(wrap, i);
  })
  }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

updateSun(data1)
            .slice {
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .slice .main-arc {
                stroke: #fff;
                stroke-width: 1px;
            }

            .slice .hidden-arc {
                fill: none;
            }

            .slice text {
                pointer-events: none;
                text-anchor: middle;
            }
<html>             
    <head>              
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>             
        <div id="sunburst"></div>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>



